# Neon Light Exports with Black Strokes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, illustrator-effects, eps

So I was working on a project and I needed a neon light effect asap so I used this asset. (It was in .eps format.)

[image: I was trying to export the right light]

When I collected it for export it did not look what it looked like in the picture. It has some sort of clipping mask which is used and it makes the black go away but it doesn't go away when being exported.

[image: It had a black gradient type of thing.]

Still I exported it and this is what I got

[image: When opened in the exported file in photoshop]

I am new to editing and stuff so I don't exactly know what's happening and why it's happening.
Please help to gain some knowledge about the stuff that's going on here. Thank you so much.

Comment: You have met something which has popped up here numerous times - a vector light effect which is planned to work only against black background. Someone has purchased  an EPS or downloaded a freebie planning to extract some parts or to edit it quickly to get an own original looking version. There are complex groups, clipping paths and group level blending modes. It's virtually impossible to separate a part and use it as is or modified except by having a black background and the right blending modes.

Comment: Also note that the main reason for this problem is that the EPS format doesn't support alpha transparency; only fully transparent or fully opaque, and nothing in between. So basically all transparency is flattened in an EPS.

Comment: Right. Gradually changing transparency is got by using a gradient which has black in the other end and by having a blending mode which makes the non-black end visible against black BG but black stays invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys, helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The next trick is a theoretical possibility. I guess drawing what you need is easier because your image looks complex.

As said in comments there are numerous shapes which have gradients from black to some color. They are layered with blending mode which makes black work like transparency against black background. The other colors in the gradients are selected so that the blending creates the wanted combination. An elementary example:

[image]

This has only 3 ellipses which are filled with different (elliptical) radial gradients. Stacked with blending mode screen they look a light effect if the background is black. Against white the stacked result is quite the same as your dirt-like excerpt.

In the next image the gradients are edited so that black is replaced with fully transparent same color as the opaque color at the other end of the gradient:

[image]

Now the stack works as well against black and white (not claiming it looks light if the background is white). The blending mode screen cannot be changed because the color mix would be different.

Unfortunately I do not know how to perform this trick automatically. You must edit every item and have them as separate layers with right blending modes (see them in the original). If you can have a black background you probably have no gradient editing problem. But you must copy the needed items one by one and stack them in the right order with right blending modes.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info, now i will try to make my own.